# Android allow user to select only bus stations on map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am making project for touristic buses and need to add possibility for drivers to add only points, which are bus stations (PKS, as pronounced in Poland) for making routes. How can I achieve that? I use Google Places API, but I don't want to call PlacePicker, because it can be used only by itself, and just provides possibilty to select Places from list (not on map). Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you don't want PlacePicker, the alternative is calling a web service. Something like `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=52.2296756%2C21.0122287&radius=1000&type=bus_station&key=YOUR_API_KEY` that will get you a list of bus stations in 1km radius.

Comment: There is one problem, if I type bus_station, Google searches only for bus stops. How can I search for Bus Stations for Buses, which go between cities (not local)?